# Constructor misunderstanding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, constructor

Normally, I've seen using **new Vector2()** while calling a constructor and instantiating an object for a class. Like:

***Vector2 v2_values = new Vector2(float x , float y);***

Here we called to the Vector2 constructor to instantiate an object of Vector2 class and stored it in *v2_values* variable. That I understood. But I don't understand the **new Vector2(2,5)** part of the code. Like how can we call an constructor in between and that too without making an object

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoverScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Rigidbody2D rd2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rd2d.AddForce(new Vector2(2,5) ,
            ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Like how can we call an constructor in between and that too without making an object" - that *does* create an instance. It just doesn't keep a local variable for the value. If you had something like `Console.WriteLine(5 + 2);` would that make sense to you? What about `Console.WriteLine("hello".ToUpperCase);`? Just keep applying the same ideas...

Comment: @JonSkeet So we can say that it's not always necessary to hold an object in a variable, right? Some objects can be created temporarily too, to be used once like in this.

Comment: Yes. Just like how you did not store the integers "2" and "5" into variables, before passing them to the `Vector2` constructor, you did not store the `Vector2` into a variable, before passing it to the `AddForce` method.

Comment: In itself, the instance of that vector is kept somewhere, namely directly as a parameter for the AddForce method.

Comment: @Sweeper But when we store values like "2" or "5" to something, it's a numeric type. And here Vector2 is a class, which is a reference type, so doesn't it need a reference variable to hold the object for it and then call it? And also can we call the constructor any class in the same way?

Comment: [`Vector2`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.html) is a struct, which is a value type. But whether it is a class or a struct doesn't matter anyway. You don't need a variable, period. You can call the constructor of any class or struct in this way.

Comment: @Sweeper Allright! Thank you very much dude! Really Appreciate your efforts!